# how to activate current navigation link with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6471/

i was trying to create a navigation bar with the active border below each navigation link, when the user hovers on it. but i want that border on the current item that was hovered. i want to remove that border from that other links. i was trying the code, but it seems my logic is not working.

my javascript

```
 $('ul > li > a').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('div').addClass('activeItemNav').siblings('div').removeClass('activeItemNav');
 });
```

Comment: Do you have to use jQuery for this simple task? CSS will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use css :hover, you don't need jQuery for this:

```css
 
ul li{
   text-align:center;
}

a:hover > div{
   height: 1px;
    width: 36px;
    border: 1px solid #fe3434;
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
           <a href="#">
            HOME
            <div></div>
           </a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">
            ABOUT
            <div></div>
           </a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">
            TEAM
            <div></div>
           </a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">
            SERVICES
            <div></div>
           </a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">
            PORTFOLIO
            <div></div>
           </a>
          </li>
          <li>
           <a href="#">
            CONTACT
            <div></div>
           </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you look for?

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6474/)

```css
ul li:hover div {
  height: 1px;
  width: 36px;
  border: 1px solid #fe3434;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
ul li{
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      HOME
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      ABOUT
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      TEAM
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      SERVICES
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      PORTFOLIO
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      CONTACT
      <div></div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using CSS instead, and set the border as an `::after` element. Then you can show this `::after` only on hover as such: `ul li:hover::after`.

An `::after` or `::before` is a pseudo element in the targeted element.

This way you do not need the unnecessary `div`.

I have updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/6475/

Answer (score 1):

This Help you :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .activeItemNav {
                height: 1px;
                width: 36px;
                border: 1px solid #fe3434;
                margin-top: 12px;
                margin: 10px auto;
            }
            ul li{
               text-align:center;
                list-style-type: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">HOME<div></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">ABOUT<div></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">TEAM<div></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SERVICES<div></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PORTFOLIO<div></div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTACT<div></div></a></li>
        </ul>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("ul li a ").mouseenter(function(){
                    $("div",this).addClass("activeItemNav");
                }).mouseleave(function(){
                     $("div",this).removeClass("activeItemNav");
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```